# Can't add views to UITableView in Interface Builder after scrolling

Tags: xcode, uitableview

This problem only starts happening after I updated to Xcode 7 recently.  Basically, I did the followings:

1) Added a UITableViewController in Interface Builder.

2) Add some dynamic prototype cells to the UITableView.

3) Since the cells are quite big, I need to scroll down to add more elements to the cells.

4) However, I can't add any elements to the cells that would extend beyond the original height of the UITableView in the Interface Builder.

For example, in the image below, I added a UIScrollView to the cell.  However, it only shows the top part of the UIScrollView.  The bottom part, which would extend beyond the original height of the UITableView, does not show up.

[Example of an UITableView with a half-visible UIScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEdPX.png)